# How to get the parameters of a generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Please take a look at the type below:

```
type User = UserSchema<{fname: string, lname: string}, string>;

{fname: string, lname: string} // I need to extract this from type User
```

Can somebody tell me how to get the first parameter of UserSchema in typescript?

Hopefully, this is clear :)

I will be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html). Something like `ExtractT<S>` as shown below:

```
// interface UserSchema<T, X> { /* ... */ }

type User = UserSchema<{fname: string, lname: string}, string>;

type ExtractT<S> = S extends UserSchema<infer R, any> ? R : never;

type Test = ExtractT<User>;
```